# Existence of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, polynomials

We are given two functions $x^3$
and $x^2|x|$
Clearly they are LI though they have Wronskian zero.

So Does there exist continuous functions p(x) and q(x)
Such that the $x^3$ and $x^2|x|$
Satisfy the ODE $y" + py'+qy =0$

If this Question is already answered please share the link I will delete this
And please don't vote down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither function is solution of a second order DE as at $x=0$ both have initial conditions zero, so at the same time have to be identical to the zero function.